# Accessing data of a .dbf using linux terminal

Tags: linux, scripting, terminal, sh, dbf

Say I have a .dbf file containing 3 rows, each with 5 (E) columns of data

Would it be possible to use terminal commands to find:

- How many rows of data this .dbf file has? (3, print this number to the terminal)
- What data a specific cell stores? (Ex: 2C has string "Hello" in it, print "Hello" to terminal)

I was thinking of using grep but I'm not sure how I would use it correctly on a .dbf

Comment: what application created the `.dbf` files? In any case, as it is almost certainly a binary file, you're going to have to either install the proper application or find a utility that can read the binary format. Linux commands are (mostly) designed to work with text files where each line ends with the `\n` char. A binary file may contain `\n` chars, but you can't guarantee that they are meant to delimit lines of data. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

`dbf` files are specialized, binary format files.  As such, it will take take specialized tools to work with it.

If you don't mind learning a little programming you can use [Python](https://www.python.org/) and my [dbf library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf) to write such simple commands.

Here's a sample script to print the length:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# this prints the number of rows in the dbf listed on the command line

import sys
import dbf

table = dbf.Table(sys.argv[1])
print(len(table))
```